# In database design: "If A -> C and B -> C, then either A->B or B->A" is false. Why?

Tags: database

This was a homework question, but I got it wrong and I'm trying to figure out why. I originally stated that it was true. I know from logic that it can be the case that A is true and B is false and thus the statement doesn't hold, but databases don't work that way, right?

I understood this to mean "A determines C", "B determines C", then either A determines B or B determines A. Which seems like it must be true, because I can't think of any examples where this is false! Could anyone post an example to illustrate why I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "is false"? Obviously, `A->C` and `B->C` does not in any way mean `A->B` or `B->A`. But what do you mean by "then either A->B or B->A" is false? Database design is not about "implies", it is about relationships. `A->B` does not in any way "imply" anything, but declares a relationship that means if you know A, you can get to B. What then does it mean that either `A->B` or `B->A` **is false**?

Comment: I'm not saying A->B or B-> is false. I am saying the statement "If A -> C and B -> C then either A->B or B->A" is false. Do you understand? I am trying to figure out why that statement is false. I cannot think of a table where A->C and B->C but not A->B or B->A.

You say that "obviously" A->C and B->C does not in any way mean that, but that's what I'm trying to figure out. How is that obvious? If A is one-to-one with C, and B is one-to-one with C, doesn't that make A and B one-to-one? Can you show me a table where this is shown?

Comment: Cross post? https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/32avph/database_design_the_statement_if_a_c_and_b_c_then/

Answer (score 0):

- A Cat is a Mammal
- A Dog is a Mammal
- A Cat is a Dog or a Dog is a Cat.

After a bit more thought, I think the "real" answer revolves somewhere in here:

[Wiki: Functional Dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Functional_dependency#Properties_and_axiomatization_of_functional_dependencies)

> Reflexivity: If Y is a subset of X, then X → Y

Since we are talking Databases, I'm fairly certain the A->C and B->C then A->B or B->A is REALLY talking about sets:

- A is a subset of C
- B is a subset of C
- A is a subset of B <- Not necessarily True
- B is a subset of A <- Not necessarily True

Given a list of mammals... Cats are a subset of Mammals... Dogs are a Subset of Mammals... Cats/Dogs aren't subsets of each other.